# Throwing an exception from a BackgroundWorker which calls an async. method (Webrequest)

Tags: c#, exception, backgroundworker, webrequest, asynccallback

- My main application creates a new BackgroundWorker X
- the DoWork event handler of X calls a method Y of my controller. This method creates the WebRequest (async.) instance and the callback using AsyncCallback.
- When the response arrives the callback method Z gets called and the content will be analyzed. It can happen that the response has an unwanted content. At that moment callback Z will throw an exception.

I want to catch this exception in my main application.
I tried it in DoWork and RunWorkerCompleted but nothing can be caught from there.

Error in RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs is always null.

Comment: So what is the solution?

Answer (score 2):

Dont know what you are doing wrong. But this works like charm.

```
        BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
        bw.DoWork += (o, s) => { throw new Exception("myMessage"); };
        bw.RunWorkerCompleted += (o, s) => { Console.WriteLine(s.Error.Message); };
        bw.RunWorkerAsync();
        Console.ReadKey(true);
```

So this means that somewhere your exception must be getting caught, and thus is prevented from propagating to the BWWorkCompletedEventArgs

Comment: My exception is thrown from a method which is called asynchronously (event handler). Maybe this is the reason?!?!?